# How to change pixels per unit for sprite after importing with WWW in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, import, sprite

I am currently making a level editor where the user imports tiles from a file, and it currently works, except for the fact that I want the pixels per unit for each imported sprite to change to 32

Here is my code:

```
//Get tiles from file
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/../Maps/" + mapName + "/Tiles/tiles.txt");
         string line = reader.ReadLine ();

         while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (line)) {
             string[] param = line.Split (',');
             foreach (TileTexture t in tileTextures) {
                 if (t.name == param [0]) {
                     Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create (t.texture, new Rect (0, 0, t.texture.width, t.texture.height), new Vector2 (0, 0));
                     sprite.pixelsPerUnit = 32;//THIS LINE DOESNT WORK, GIVES READONLY ERROR
                     Tile tile = new Tile (param[0], sprite, new Vector2(float.Parse(param[1]), float.Parse(param[2])));
                     tile.sprite.texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
                     tiles.Add (tile);
                 }
             }

             line = reader.ReadLine ();
         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the function [Sprite.Create()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) we see that the function signature is

```
public static Sprite Create(Texture2D texture, 
                            Rect rect, 
                            Vector2 pivot, 
                            float pixelsPerUnit = 100.0f, 
                            uint extrude = 0, 
                            SpriteMeshType meshType = SpriteMeshType.Tight, 
                            Vector4 border = Vector4.zero);
```

We see that we can pass the `pixelsPerUnit` as an optional parameter into the function. You can only do this here, and you cannot change it later, because, as you have found out, the field `pixelsPerUnit` is `readonly` field (meaning it cannot be changed). So, you just need to pass in your `32f` here. Correct code would be

```
if (t.name == param [0]) {
                 Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create (t.texture, new Rect (0, 0, t.texture.width, t.texture.height), new Vector2 (0, 0), 32f);
                 Tile tile = new Tile (param[0], sprite, new Vector2(float.Parse(param[1]), float.Parse(param[2])));
                 tile.sprite.texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
                 tiles.Add (tile);
             }
```

Comment: Thank you, i will mark your question as right as soon as I can :D